# Date convertion Issue in Ms sql

Tags: sql-server

My table name as `tbl_event`

[image]

`Event_ExpiryDate`, `Event_Date` fields data type is varchar, I have using the following query for getting data from the table:

```
select * from tbl_event
WHERE 
LEFT (CONVERT(VARCHAR,Event_ExpiryDate,103),12)>= LEFT(CONVERT(varchar,GetDate(),103),12) and
 LEFT (CONVERT(VARCHAR,Event_Date,103),12)<= LEFT(CONVERT(varchar,GetDate(),103),12)
```

but I am getting a result like this

[image]

1 data to be missing. Why? this issue only on some month's date only. Months are 2,4,8,12

Comment: If `Event_ExpiryDate` is a varchar, why are you converting it to a varchar? More importantly, why are you storing dates as strings?

Comment: If `Event_ExpiryDate` and `Event_Date` are *dates* **why** are they a `varchar`? Unless it's intentional that a date like `2010-01-30` is **after** `2019-12-01`? If not, it will be in your data (as it uses the format `dd/MM/yyyy`). Use the right data type, and there isn't a problem; that's the real solution.

Comment: This is a running project so we cannot update the table structure , any other suggestions please,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *real* problem here is your data, and that you're using the wrong data type. Fix the data type, fix the problem.

You can fix that by firstly changing your `varchar` representation of a date to an unambiguous Date format, `yyyyMMdd` (This assumes your dates are in the format `dd/MM/yyyy`):

```
UPDATE dbo.tbl_event
SET Event_Date = CONVERT(varchar(8),CONVERT(date,Event_Date,103),112),
    Created_Date = CONVERT(varchar(8),CONVERT(date,Created_Date,103),112),
    Event_ExpiryDate = CONVERT(varchar(8),CONVERT(date,Event_ExpiryDate,103),112);
```

Then you can `ALTER` the table to fix your data types:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tbl_event ALTER COLUMN Event_Date date NULL; --Use NOT NULL if not NULLable
ALTER TABLE dbo.tbl_event ALTER COLUMN Created_Date date NULL; --Use NOT NULL if not NULLable
ALTER TABLE dbo.tbl_event ALTER COLUMN Event_ExpiryDate date NULL; --Use NOT NULL if not NULLable
```

*Note: If any of your dates have bad values, for example `'31/04/2019'`, the above will fail. You can get around this by changing the `CONVERT` functions to `TRY_CONVERT`, **however** any values that fail to convert* will *have the value `NULL`. If your columns have the `NOT NULL` property you will need to ensure you handle that too. If you* do *have bad values in your table, I strongly suggest taking a backup, or copy of the database/table first, so that you have a historical copy. (Of course, does a date like `'31/04/2019'` or `'12/13/2018'` have any meaning anyway?)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use only `convert()` :

```
where convert(date, Event_ExpiryDate, 103) >= convert(date, getdate()) and
      convert(date, Event_Date, 103) <= convert(date, getdate());
```

However, storing `varchar` date is really bad idea. It will lead you lots of in trouble.